# Interesting SEO scenario - 301 part of a website

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, seo, multiple-domains

Anyone had any experiences with redirecting part of a website to whole new domain? Here is what we have done:

Originally had a forum on **websiteA**, due to spam and hacking the forum was closed down as it was having negative effects on position

The whole forum and threads were 301 redirected to **websiteA** homepage.

Later we decided to have a general forum which is on a newly registered domain **websiteB** the original forum was 301 redirected to **websiteB/theme1** now we have found a decrease in position for a general one word term **websiteA** was ranking for.

We did this as people were coming to our site through google by searching "theme1 forum" though in fact there was no forum there anymore, so it seems logical to have done this redirection.

I know the 301 is a permanent redirect but on this occasion it seemed logical in that there were many backlinks to the non existen forum and **websiteA** no longer had a forum on it!

Just wondered if anyone has gone through a similar experience and what the outcome was.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in your case a "double" 301 redirect with the latest forward to websiteB could be not well considered by Google or the new Panda Algo could rank your website in a different way, despite you 301 redirect.